# How to minimize application to tray by using command line argument

Tags: c#

How can i minimize application to system tray by using command line argument.

eg:when i open my application using command line like this.
c:\myfile.exe totray

i writed some code for that but it never worked.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if (args.Length >0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(args[0]);
            }
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }
```

Here the messagebox is showing with my argument "totray".
so i just added code like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if (args.Length >0)
            {
               // MessageBox.Show(args[0]);
                if (args[0] == "totray") {
                    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
                    frm1.Hide();
                }
            }
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }
```

But this idea is not working.
is it possible to do get the argument to the form?
what code i need to write here?

Comment: What isn't working? What happens, and what should happen?

Comment: what are your results with debugging?  Put in some breakpoints, do it make it to both/either if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.CommandLine` contains the arguments passed on the command line.
Better [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) that returns a string array like the string[] args passed to the main method, but with the first argument being the executable file name.

Not sure if you need moving the code to the form_load event or in the form contructor.

[MSDN Refs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend passing a bool into the `Form` constructor, and deciding whether to minimize based on that.

Add this constructor to `Form1`:

```
public Form1(bool minimize) : this()
{
    if (minimize)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it in `Main` like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1(args.Contains("totray")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to call the `-tray` parameter.see [mozilla support command line parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Command_Line_Options)